# Why do you have to rerun the previous code box in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I started using Jupyter notebook today. I used to only use `python` or just a text editor.

I'm a bit confused about how the workflow works. Sometimes when I compute some variable `x` in, say, code box 1 and then I use it in code box 2, if I execute code box 1 first and then 2, it'll work. Sometimes when I execute code box 2 by itself, it'll say `x` is undefined, but shouldn't it store the result from a previous run?

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter's kernel acts like a new console. Forget the order of the cells as they are displayed. That is irrelevant, unless your are hitting "Run all", in which case the notebook decides to run the cells in the up to down order. When you use shift-enter to run an individual cell, you are choosing the order they are being run. Restart the kernel if you want to start fresh.

Comment: But doesn't it save variables after you've executed them?

Comment: yeah, did you restart the kernel though? Hard to tell what's going on without seeing the cells you are running.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what that means. Here's a screenshot that I can use to describe what's going on. https://imgur.com/a/leQPQkQ     When I execute the `[214]` block, it gives me that error. But if I start executing from the `[212]` block, I don't get that error.

Comment: When I restarted the kernel, I get the same error. Hmm, that's weird.

Comment: The error is an indexing one rather than a naming error. The problem, thus, appears to be with your variable `theta` rather than the jupyter notebook. Check `len(theta.shape)>=2`

Comment: Hmm you're right, but when I executed the first block before the second previously, I wasn't always getting the error for some reason.

Comment: It might have to do with your `y_train` or `x_train` since that's how you are defining `theta`. Sometimes when I play around with code in jupyter, (deleting cells, running cells, or changing order), I'll end up in a situation like that where it inconsistently works. That's why I recommend restarting the kernel and hitting "Run all" after messing with the code to make sure all the steps are properly documented.